# Convert Exponential to Integer

Tags: c#, parsing, exponential

I have the following string: `2.200000000000E+09`

If I do the following:

```
float.Parse("2.200000000000E+09") = 2.2E+9
```

If I do:

```
Int64.Parse("2.200000000000E+09")
```

I was expecting:

```
2200000000
```

Instead I get a format exception so what is the easiest way to get the exponential to integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var i = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("2.200000000000E+09",
                         NumberStyles.Float ,
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: +1 for [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). i think `Float` includes exponent by default though.

Comment: But you can still parse this string to `uint` or `long` with no overflow, but the `NumberStyles` flag is needed.

Comment: Note that `Float` already has the `AllowExponent` flag as a component of it; there is no need to OR that flag onto it.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float` like:

```
Int64.Parse("2.200000000000E+09", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Comment: You could use `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any` of course or other ones that fit, but this one seems safer...

Comment: This appears to be what the Original Poster asks for. The overload [`long.Parse(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3.aspx) implicitly uses `NumberStyles.Integer` which is not suited for the string in question. Read on the overload [`long.Parse(string, NumberStyles)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkw23d3e.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using

```
decimal x = decimal.Parse("2.200000000000E+09", NumberStyles.Float);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this using
>
> decimal x = decimal.Parse("2.200000000000E+09", NumberStyles.Float);

@Bhushan Firake. this line of code: "`decimal x = decimal.Parse("2.200000000000E+09", NumberStyles.Float);`" actualy helped me, but I found out that the "d" of `decimal.Parse` has to be written in Capital D like this -> `Decimal.Parse(`. And I changed the second parameter to `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any`. So the correct Code should actualy look like this: `decimal StringToNumVar = Decimal.Parse(MyString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);`